# How to create a model relation through a join Bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I am trying to create a relation between `Merchants` and `Transactions` using Bookshelf.

- one transaction can have multiple vouchers
- one voucher contains the transaction key and the merchant key
- Merchant needs to be able to pull out all unique transactions

My models are defined below:

```
var Voucher = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'vouchers',

  transaction: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Transaction);
  },

  merchant: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Merchant);
  }
});


var Transaction = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'transactions',

  vouchers: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Voucher);
  }
});


var Merchant = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: 'merchants',


  vouchers: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Voucher);
  },

  transactions: function() {
    //???
  }
});
```

#### Schema

```
var schema = {
  merchants: {
    id: {type: 'increments', nullable: false, primary: true},
    category_id: {type: 'integer', nullable: false, unsigned: true, references: 'categories.id'},
    name: {type: 'string', maxlength: 150, nullable: false},
    slug: {type: 'string', maxlength: 150, nullable: false, unique: true},
    email: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: false},
    tel: {type: 'string', maxlength: 64, nullable: false},
    location_name: {type: 'string', maxlength: 150, nullable: false},
    province: {type: 'string', maxlength: 64, nullable: false},
    city: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: false},
    town: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: true},
    address: {type: 'text', maxlength: 2000, nullable: false},
    created_at: {type: 'dateTime', nullable: false},
    updated_at: {type: 'dateTime', nullable: true}
  },

  transactions: {
    id: {type: 'increments', nullable: false, primary: true}, 
    user_id: {type: 'integer', nullable: false, unsigned: true, references: 'users.id'},
    uuid: {type: 'string', maxlength: 128, nullable: false},
    raw: {type: 'text', maxlength: 2000, nullable: false},
    total_amount: {type: 'integer', nullable: false},
    total_vouchers: {type: 'integer', nullable: false},
    total_postages: {type: 'integer', nullable: true},
    created_at: {type: 'dateTime', nullable: false},
    updated_at: {type: 'dateTime', nullable: true}
  },

  vouchers: {
    id: {type: 'increments', nullable: false, primary: true}, 
    transaction_id: {type: 'integer', nullable: false, unsigned: true, references: 'transactions.id'},
    merchant_id: {type: 'integer', nullable: false, unsigned: true, references: 'merchants.id'},
    user_id: {type: 'integer', nullable: false, unsigned: true, references: 'users.id'},
    vouchertemplate_id: {type: 'integer', nullable: false, unsigned: true, references: 'vouchertemplates.id'},
    voucher_number: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: false},
    value: {type: 'integer', nullable: false},
    redeemed_value: {type: 'integer', nullable: false, defaultTo: 0},
    message: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: false},
    recipient_name: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: false},
    created_at: {type: 'dateTime', nullable: false},
    updated_at: {type: 'dateTime', nullable: true}
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your schema. Neither merchant nor transaction posses any id to one or another. Currently you can't join them. Perhaps modify schema a bit?